# Deactivate Anti-Blue Light

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, desktop-computer

I have 3 monitors and 2 of them are the same. I bought one that was "better" but I didn't read the product sheet and apparently it came with something called "Anti-Blue Light" and it looks like urine in it (yellow tint).

**Specs**

- Manufacturer website: http://aoc-europe.com/en/products/g2460vq6
- Monitor model: G2460VQ6
- I have a Nvidia gpu

**Question**

*Is there away to disable this?*

Comment: Could it be that your colour temperature is set too low? I can easily reproduce this on my LG E2742 by setting the colour temperature to 4000K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to find info on the features aside from press-release science free content, but it looks like the blue filters are actually a cut filter in the near-UV spectrum, which is probably something they have always needed to do but only recently became a sales bullet point. Note they also say it ought not affect color.

**However**, your description, though a little vague, indicates that you probably have a bad ICC profile attached to the monitor. You should check the color management settings, and note that the OS and the GPU can both make changes, so for the best result, choose one to handle it and disable it on the other.

I usually opt for the OS to handle it.